# Need to restore New project > Installed >Templates > Visual C# > Cloud > Quickstarts

Tags: templates, azure, sdk, visual-studio-2015, storage

I was having trouble following the MVA course "Microsoft Azure Fundamentals: Storage and Data" in the "How do I: Perform Common Tasks with Azure Table Storage" module at timestamp 00:07:55, where Bob Tabor starts using a "New project > Installed >Templates > Visual C# > Cloud > Quickstarts > Azure Table Storage" template.

I used to have the same quickstarts templates, but deleted them by mistake trying to solve a problem.

When I followed the course and created a new project with the "Azure Table Storage" template, Visual Studio Community 2015 kept giving me a Cloud Configuration Namespace missing error (or something liike that).

After giving up trying to fix that problem directly, I thought I could fix it by installing updated templates.  When no update option was shown for the templates, I tried to uninstall and reinstall the Quickstarts templates.

Uninstalling was easy.  But, eight hours later, I am giving up reinstalling and asking for help.

I installed VS2015 update 2 and Azure SDK 2.9, then did a full VS "Repair" .  But the Quickstarts templates still have not reappeared. I can't find anything by browsing online in "Tools > Extensions and Updates" or in "Tools > NuGet Package Manager" or just plain internet browsing including NuGet and GitHub sites that downloads and re-installs the Quickstarts" templates.

The closest I think I got was to download "https://github.com/Azure/azure-storage-net" but then I couldn't figure out how to "execute" the zip to reinstall the missing templates.

Can anyone help?

[Quickstarts incorrectly deleted from New project > Installed >Templates > Visual C# > Cloud](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jxP7H.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

I was hoping for an easier answer. But when nobody chimed in I went ahead and uninstalled Visual Studio Community 2015 -- taking the opportunity in Control Panel to also uninstall anything and everything that looked like it was related.

Reinstalling brought back everything including the missing Quickstarts.  It was probably overkill and wasted more time than necessary.  But at least it unblocked my progress.  Thanks to anyone that looked at the problem and gave it any thought.